# React Navigation V5, TabNavigation sharing props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-v5

In may Dashboard screen which is created using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`, and has 5 screens.
I want to achieve that for example after doing some function in screen1, then i want screen2 to make a specific function, without rendering any screen again.
So my problem was how to make the tabs connected and know about each other.
I am looking to share state between screens or props.
That's my DashBoard Code (summarized).

```
function Switch0({navigation, route}) {return <Screen0 navigation = {navigation} route={route}/>}
function Switch1({navigation, route}) {return <Screen1 navigation = {navigation} route={route}/>}
function Switch2({navigation, route}) {return <Screen2 navigation = {navigation} route={route}/>}
function Switch3({navigation, route}) {return <Screen3 navigation = {navigation} route={route}/>}
function Switch4({navigation, route}) {return <Screen4 navigation = {navigation} route={route}/>}

export default class DashBoard1 extends React.Component {

  render(){
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="MyTeams" component={Switch0} options={navigationOptions0} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Matches" component={Switch1} options={navigationOptions1}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="PlayerMarket" component={Switch2} options={navigationOptions2}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Courts" component={Switch3} options={navigationOptions3}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Tournaments" component={Switch4} options={navigationOptions4}/>
    </Tab.Navigator> 
  );
}
```

Comment: You will need an app state provider above all the screens.

Comment: I tried to make a state in the DashBoard class and send it to the 5 screens, also i made a function to change the state of the DashBoard and also pass it to the 5 screens and it worked. However, when the DashBoard state changes the screens rerendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you should wrap you `AppContainer` with some state provider.

```
import { StoreProvider } from 'store';

<StoreProvider>
  <AppContainer />
</StoreProvider>
```

This store provider can be made using `redux`. https://redux.js.org
Or if you are comfortable with hooks, you can try `React context Api`, something this and write your actions and reducers. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

```
import Reducer, { initialState } from './reducers';
import useActions from './actions';

export const Store = React.createContext();

export const StoreProvider = props => {
  const { children } = props;

  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
  const actions = useActions(state, dispatch);
  const value = { state, dispatch, actions };

  return <Store.Provider value={value}>{children}</Store.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: okay, thank you. I will look at them i think this might be the only solution.

Comment: Yes sure i am implementing redux now.

Comment: A big thank you, i implemented it and it is working fine.